# ORA-00904 - "NORM": invalid identifier - string in dynamic sql

Tags: oracle11g

Im trying to execute below section of code but get an ORA-00904 error.

```
Declare
i_status varchar2(4) := 'NORM';
vsql varchar2(4000);
...
...
Begin
...
...<Part of larger dynamic sql>
  If i_status is not null Then
  vSql := vSql || ' And account.astatus = ' ||i_status|| '';
  End if;

execute immediate (vSql) into tmp,ssn;

<Do something with tmp, ssn>

End;
```

An exception is raised at line "execute immediate" with error 
ORA-00904 - "NORM": invalid identifier

column account.astatus has type char(4 byte)

I assume the problem is that I am trying to pass string variable NORM in the where clause without adding quotes ' '. How do get around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to use bind variables, meaning you avoid the whole thorny issue of sql injection that you open yourself up to when you hardcode your variables into the dynamic sql. You also save yourself the faff of having to work out how to include the single-quotes to go around the string that your dynamic sql is currently missing.

Using bind variables, your code becomes:

```
Declare
  i_status varchar2(4) := 'NORM';
  vsql varchar2(4000);
  ...
  ...
Begin
  ...
  ...<Part of larger dynamic sql>

  If i_status is not null Then
    vSql := vSql || ' And account.astatus = :i_status';
  End if;

  execute immediate (vSql) into tmp,ssn using i_status;

  <Do something with tmp, ssn>

End;
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily dig into your code and check where the issue exist by printing your VSQL before executing it.

```
 Declare
    i_status varchar2(10) := 'NORM';
    vsql varchar2(4000):= 'Select * from dual where 1=3';

    Begin

      If i_status is not null Then
      vSql := vSql || ' And account.astatus = ' ||i_status|| '';
      End if;

      dbms_output.put_line(vSql);

      --execute immediate (vSql) into tmp,ssn;        

    End;
```

When you run this block you can see the statement that is getting generated which shows :

> Select * from dual where 1=3 And account.astatus = NORM

Now you can easily note that your `account.astatus = NORM` is not correct so you can replace it with:

```
i_status varchar2(10) := '''NORM''';
```

or using q quotes:

```
i_status varchar2(10) := q'['NORM']';
```

Nevertheless what Boneist mentioned is the best practice which avoids sql injection.